# Is "fake teeth" correct?

Tags: expressions, grammaticality

Is the phrase "fake teeth" correct? I googled it and found out that it is used. But my English tutor says that this phrase is incorrect and the book from Hillside Press had this phrase as a mistake.

So what is true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe your English tutor wants you to say "**false teeth**" instead. Google count is 85K for "fake teeth" and 442K for "false teeth".

Note that in the Wikipedia, both "false teeth" and "fake teeth" redirect to the page on [dentures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_teeth). However, in general, while "false teeth" is used as a synonym for dentures, "fake teeth" is more for things like vampire teeth that people wear in Halloween for fun.

Comment: Martha, Cindi deleted her comments. But she had basically written what I described in my last sentence above. I will delete the reference to avoid any confusion for future readers.

Comment: re: fake vs false teeth: I feel that false teeth are real teeth, just not true (i.e. natural) teeth. False teeth are a replacement for your natural teeth. Fake teeth aren't real teeth. So while I understand wikipedia merging the terms, I'd say there is still a subtle distinction and the tutor may be on the right track.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New, that's what I meant by "However, in general, while "false teeth" is used as a synonym for dentures, "fake teeth" is more for things like vampire teeth that people wear in Halloween for fun. "

Comment: Yes.  I just wanted to expand on it to illustrate the difference between "fake" and "false".

Answer (score 0):

Any language teacher that say a phrase is "incorrect" has no understanding of how language actually works. You can say that a term is more common and is the accepted way of saying a thing but if enough people use a word or phrase "incorrectly" then it becomes the accepted standard and the meaning changes. Language is not math and there are no "correct" answers. In language might makes right.

Comment: thank you:) When i get the book i will post here the complete example..